# Debian 10 preseeded two disk install

Tags: debian, partition, system-installation, preseed

I need to make preseed file that installs system on lesser disk and /var -- on larger. I was told that I'd require scripts for this since I don't want to use RAID or LVM. I am unaware, though, about the way such scripts are written. Could you give me any advice or working example?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I'd recommend using a recipe without a separate `/var`, then moving the contents of `/target/var` into a freshly created filesystem and adding the corresponding `fstab` line via something like

```
d-i preseed/late_command string mkfs.xfs /dev/sdX && mount /dev/sdX /mnt && mv /target/var/* /mnt && umount /mnt && echo /dev/sdX /var xfs default 0 2 >>/target/etc/fstab
```

(see the [Installation Guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/apbs05.en.html#preseed-hooks); if `/mnt` does not exists, try something else, maybe `/target/mnt`). Of course this is inconvenient if your custom installation puts lots of data there. But doing it properly from the start is [rather more complicated](http://iks.cs.ovgu.de/~elkner/tmp/partman-doc.html/): you'd have to extend the partman installer component by creating a custom udeb or adding files to the installer initrd.